# circle disappears in max zooming for mapbox

Tags: ember.js

In map i created marker in that i create  circle layer when you zoom the without marker circle layer coming about to max zoom but if any marker is there it will show about level 17 (when i click the marker it will zoom 18 that time disappears the circle  layer  )

Comment: What does this have to do with ember?

Comment: I want show in max zoom geofences circle  display , without marker (icon)  It display about max zoom when click on the marker icon

Comment: I want show in max zoom geofences circle  display , without marker (icon)  It display about max zoom but when in geofences click on the marker icon (i set if click on marker it will max zoom display the icon  with popup  details about icon  ) but it disappears on click how to handle this problem give me solution  you can use javascript , jquery ,lodash

Comment: which library is used for map?